# matplotlib connecting the dots in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize some data regarding the time at which the process was running or alive and the time it was idle. For each process, I have `a_x_axis` the time at which process started running and `a_live_for` is the time it was alive after it woke up. I have two data points in for each process. I am trying to connect these two dots by a line by connecting 1st green dot with the first red dot and second green dot with the second red dot and so on, so I can see alive and idle time for each process in the large data set. I looked into scatter plot examples but could not find any way to solve this issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_x_axis = [32, 30, 40, 50, 60, 78]
a_live = [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4]

a_alive_for = [a + b for a, b in zip(a_x_axis, a_live)]

b_x_axis = [22, 25, 45, 55, 60, 72]
b_live = [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4]
b_alive_for = [a + b for a, b in zip(b_x_axis, b_live)]

a_y_axis = []
b_y_axis = []

for i in range(0, len(a_x_axis)):
    a_y_axis.append('process-1')
    b_y_axis.append('process-2')


print("size of a: %s" % len(a_x_axis))
print("size of a: %s" % len(a_y_axis))
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.scatter(a_x_axis, [1]*len(a_x_axis))
plt.scatter(a_alive_for, [1]*len(a_x_axis))

plt.scatter(b_x_axis, [2]*len(b_x_axis))
plt.scatter(b_alive_for, [2]*len(b_x_axis))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to connect both processes through a line? Or a line representing each process separately?

Comment: in other words, you want to connect (for example) green and blue dots, then red and orange ones? scatter is specifically not to connect data points. You just want to stack two variables and sort them

Comment: I want to connect first `a_x_axis` value with the first `a_alive_for` value and second with the second values. In the figure, to connect with first green dot with the first red dot and second green dot with second red dot and so on.

Comment: Can you produce a n error free minimal code. You appending strings into your list (`a_y_axis.append('process-1')`) and trying to plot those strings.

Comment: @HarvIpan this is error free code. The figure attached is generated by this code.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat, it is not. I ran the code and y axis has strings that you are trying to scatterplot.

Comment: it is working on my system, anyway... I made the necessary changes, you can check it now.

Comment: @HarvIpan please let me know if it is still not working.

Comment: Does it really matter to be the one green one red, or is just that you want them sorted by time?

Comment: Since you mainly want to see, when processes are active and inactive - wouldn't a simple `hbar` for each `x_alive` present this information with less visual noise?

Comment: @anishtain4 Actually, it does not matter. It is just my understanding of what this graph should look like. The data I represented is just for a simple example. The whole purpose to differentiate between the time the process was working and the time the process was idle. Please let me know, if you have any suggestion on this. thanks

Comment: @Mr.T It would be really cool if I can replace this dot line graph with a bar representing the time process was running but that is not a bar graph. I am not sure what you suggested. Is the bar represents the process was running at particular time and no bar represents process was idle at that particular time? what if there are 10 processess?

Comment: As you've already marked the submitted answer works fine. I didn't realise you want to pair them. My understanding was that you wanted to connect all the dots in that order.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat If I wanted to analyse ten processes that constantly go on an off, I would you use [such a broken bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-broken-barh-py) with ten colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_x_axis = [32, 30, 40, 50, 60, 78]
a_live = [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4]

a_alive_for = [a + b for a, b in zip(a_x_axis, a_live)]

b_x_axis = [22, 25, 45, 55, 60, 72]
b_live = [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4]
b_alive_for = [a + b for a, b in zip(b_x_axis, b_live)]

a_y_axis = []
b_y_axis = []

for i in range(0, len(a_x_axis)):
    a_y_axis.append('process-1')
    b_y_axis.append('process-2')


print("size of a: %s" % len(a_x_axis))
print("size of a: %s" % len(a_y_axis))
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.scatter(a_x_axis, [1]*len(a_x_axis))
plt.scatter(a_alive_for, [1]*len(a_x_axis))

plt.scatter(b_x_axis, [2]*len(b_x_axis))
plt.scatter(b_alive_for, [2]*len(b_x_axis))

for i in range(0, len(a_x_axis)):
    plt.plot([a_x_axis[i],a_alive_for[i]], [1,1], 'green')

for i in range(0, len(b_x_axis)):
    plt.plot([b_x_axis[i],b_alive_for[i]], [2,2], 'green')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat Glad to help. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

`scatter` is just not the tool for plotting lines, it's `plot`. And it accepts 2D-arrays of x- and y-coordinates, so you don't have to manually iterate over lists. So you would need sth like

```
plt.plot([a_x_axis, a_alive_for], [[1]*n,[1]*n], 'green')
```

with `n = len(a_x_axis)`.

However, you could structure your data much better in numpy arrays or pandas dataframes where you can set titles for columns, too. (Is it that, what you wanted to achieve by appending 'process-x' to your data lists...?)

Also, the colors of your markers seem to me not chosen by purpose; if you want to have them the same like the lines you could even leave `scatter` completely away.